# AdMob NativeAds in Compose

Tags: kotlin, admob, composable

I'm looking for the latest Kotlin code to implement NativeAds from Google AdMob.

None of Google's official documentation on AdMob NativeAds has been updated to incorporate Kotlin `Composables`.  Additionally, templates on [GitHub](https://github.com/ahmetfurkans/GamerApp) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71128462/how-to-display-native-ads-via-jetpack-compose) are also outdated.

I'm looking for something that implements a barebones NativeAd based on today's APIs.  I can add bells and whistles later.